# What's the appropriate directory structure for a spring boot web app so that the home page automatically opens when the program is run?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, directory

I've created this project through Spring Boot. It's a full stack web app that takes information from a user, validates it, sanitizes it, authorizes it, and then sends it to a database. It also can retrieve data from a database.

The problem is that, when the project runs, it should open the home page automatically. Instead, I have to navigate to it manually through a browser, resulting in Access Control Allow Origin issues (as it appears that AJAX is being sent cross origin).

My current directory structure is like this:

C:\Users\workspace\Repository\Project\src\main\resources\templates

Within this templates folder, I have my webpages and config folders. These config folders contain the Javascript files.

I've looked at other projects I've created, and directory structure is very different, but they all use jsps. They look like this:

C:\Users\workspace\CapstoneProject\src\main\webapp\jsp

This directory has all the jsps in it, and they start with the project.

What is the appropriate directory structure so that they start with the project? I've googled this and looked on Spring's website but have found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The location is less important and it depends on your ant/maven/gradle/script of building your artifact for example War file which it should be copied to webapps folder and then folder for resource type as jsp/css/js/html

Static resources as html can be outside your war in a separate resource folder.

According to [tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html) it depends on your size of the application:

> *.html, *.jsp, etc. - The HTML and JSP pages, along with other files that must be visible to the client browser (such as JavaScript,
>   stylesheet files, and images) for your application. In larger
>   applications you may choose to divide these files into a subdirectory
>   hierarchy, but for smaller apps, it is generally much simpler to
>   maintain only a single directory for these files.

Comment: Should the folder holding my .html files be named jsp even if they're not jsps?

I am using Gradle by the way.

Comment: I think and we are using a separate html folder